# Nulling pointers defined within function

Tags: c++, c++11

In the codebase I inherited, I notice that the previous coder would null pointers init'ed within the function before the function closes.

Something like:

```
void MainClass::run() {

MyClass* _classPtr = GetClassPtr(); // Assume no problems here.

// do stuff to _classPtr

_classPtr = nullptr; // Is this even necessary?

return;
}
```

I find it unnecessary since the pointer's memory (Not the object itself, just the pointer) should be freed up at function close. Is that true?

Comment: Does `GetClassPtr()` create the object? Who is responsible for deleting it?

Comment: Let's just say that it only returns a pointer. No object is created in the call.

Comment: Then it sounds like you don't own the pointer, so you should not delete it and setting it to nullptr makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary to do this. When the function goes out of scope the the memory used by the pointer will be release regardless of what it's set to. However, the object pointed to will not be released.

This is probably just a coding standard adopted by the previous developer.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `_classPtr` will disappear when it goes out of scope, which happens when the function returns, so no there's no need to reassign it to be a null pointer.

Talking about returning, once the function reaches its end, it will return automatically, there's no need for an explicit return at the end of a function without return value.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it's just a personal programming practice, and does not accomplish anything. The compiler is likely to optimize the whole thing away, so this will not actually end up producing any actual code at run time.

It could also be remnants of prior versions of this functions, that might have had more code that followed, but it was removed, except that the re-initialization part was forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

only the memory allocated in the heap i.e memory initialized using `new` operator are not freed at closing the functions .

Local variables or auto variables defined inside the functions would be automatically freed .

Answer (score 0):

One useful pattern that could be used is that each pointer is nulled immediately after the resources it holds are recycled.

If a pointers resources need not be recycled, and is no longer going to be used, it is nulled without the recycling.

Then, at any point in the function while debugging or reasoning about it, the only non-zero pointers are those that have "live" (valid) memory, or are in the midst of being cleaned up.

If you know a given pointer always holds a resource, you can "blindly" do an "if (ptr) delete ptr; ptr=0;` without worrying that someone has already cleaned it up.

On the other hand, a line of code saying `ptr=0;` without a delete right next to it tells you that the pointer *was not* owning any memory, as opposed to it being leaked.  (or, someone deleted the delete accidentally, which is less likely)

You might think this is inefficient; but if the compiler can prove that nobody will read a pointer after a point where you set it to zero, the compiler can (under the as-if rule) *remove the nulling of the pointer*.

So the cost is zero, if the compiler can figure it out.  If the code is complex enough that the compiler *cannot* figure it out, maybe nulling it redundantly would be a good idea anyhow?